How long should users wait for their hearts to refill in a gamified training platform we are developing?
We are creating a training platform and are looking for the sweet spot for how long users should wait for their hearts to refresh. Do you have any thoughts?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I’m seeking recommendations on how long users should wait for their in-game "hearts" to refresh in the training platform we are currently developing. These hearts are deducted when users provide incorrect answers during assessments. We want to find the ideal wait time that maintains user engagement without causing frustration or discouraging participation. What would be a good balance between keeping users motivated and allowing them time to reflect before attempting another assessment?

Thank you for the added context. But it is still not clear why it is automated. Do you deduct hearts for every wrong question or based on average score for failing the overall assessment? If a user has failed an assessment and needs time to prepare for the next one, why is it time boxed? Why does the user need to wait for the hearts to refresh? Why not start new with full health without any delays if the user wants to?

Thank you for your questions! To clarify, hearts are deducted for each wrong answer, not based on the average score. The assessment isn't time-boxed; users can attempt it as long as they have enough hearts. The reason we have a timer for hearts to refresh is to give users some breathing room and to encourage them to take time to review and digest the course material. This break helps ensure they’re more prepared when they attempt the assessment again, rather than rushing through it.

As stated earlier, please reframe the question with all these details as well as your target audience. The type of users you have in mind has not been mentioned. The time-period will vary based on age and other factors.

The only right way would be to provide a function to "Replenish hearts" that can be executed by the user at free will (but it could cost "something").
Because either the hearts are used to indicate how close to be at "game over" - or you just annoy the "player"/trainee to need to wait a certain amount of time to replenish the hearts anyway - so hearts become just useless in function.
The timer for refreshing only works if it is not a "real time timer" but something like a per question timer: For each three consecutive right answers you can gain one heart for example. Or after each three questions a bonus question appears which allows to gain one heart again.
